# Making Relation data available in eloquent collection when searching a Algolia index

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, algolia, laravel-scout

I have a **Laravel 5.7** application using **Scout Extended** to integrate **Algolia** search functionality. In the application I have a model called **"Prospect"** that has **belongsTo** relationships with two other Models: **"State"** & **"FoodCat"**.

I am trying to figure out how to include the relationship data for **"State"** & **"FoodCat"** with the search results when searching using the Algolia index.

The relationship data has been included in the search index by extending **toSearchableArray()** in the Prospect model.

[https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/indexing/configure-searchable-data/#relationships]

However, the relationship data is not available in the Eloquent collection after searching. It is only available by looping through the raw data array...

---

Looking at the raw data array, both the **"State"** and the **"FoodCat"** relation data is available in the search index when the raw data is outputted:

...out example of: **Prospect::search('')->raw()**

```
array:9 [▼
  "hits" => array:20 [▼
    0 => array:33 [▼
      "id" => 251
      "name" => "Pizza House & Grille"
      "contact_fname" => null
      "contact_lname" => null
      "contact_title" => null
      "food_cat_id" => 1
      "phone" => 6195610325
      "fax" => null
      "website" => ""
      "address" => "12580 Lakeshore Drive"
      "address2" => null
      "city" => "Lakeside"
      "state_id" => 5
      "zip" => 92040
      "region_id" => 1
      "latitude" => 38.975201
      "longitude" => -122.676003
      "sic_desc" => "Pizza Restaurants"
      "lead_source" => "Manual"
      "owner_type" => null
      "contacted" => 0
      "contacted_timestamp" => null
      "response_notes" => "Lorem Ipsum Something Something"
      "user_id" => null
      "created_at" => 1319545964
      "updated_at" => 1550950060
      "foodcat" => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "title" => "Pizza/Italian"
        "slug" => "Pizza-Italian"
      ]
      "state" => array:4 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "name" => "California"
        "abbr" => "CA"
        "active" => 1
      ]
      "_geoloc" => array:2 [▶]
      "food_cat_title" => "Pizza/Italian"
      "_tags" => array:1 [▶]
      "objectID" => "App\Prospect::251"
      "_highlightResult" => array:9 [▶]
    ]
```

---

However when searching the index and fetching the results into an eloquent collection the "State" & "FoodCat" data is not available...

...example output of: **Prospect::search('')->get()**

```
Collection {#650 ▼
  #items: array:20 [▼
    0 => Prospect {#713 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "prospects"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:26 [▶]
      #original: array:26 [▼
        "id" => 333
        "name" => "test"
        "contact_fname" => "test"
        "contact_lname" => "test"
        "contact_title" => "test"
        "food_cat_id" => 1
        "phone" => "6195551212"
        "fax" => ""
        "website" => ""
        "address" => "123 mian"
        "address2" => ""
        "city" => "sd"
        "state_id" => 5
        "zip" => 92101
        "region_id" => 1
        "latitude" => "32.785301"
        "longitude" => "-117.111000"
        "sic_desc" => "Pizza"
        "lead_source" => "Manual"
        "owner_type" => ""
        "contacted" => 0
        "contacted_timestamp" => null
        "response_notes" => ""
        "user_id" => null
        "created_at" => "2019-03-19 11:08:57"
        "updated_at" => "2019-03-19 11:08:57"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #scoutMetadata: array:1 [▶]
    }
```

**How can I make the same relation data available to the eloquent collection after searching the Algolia index?**

---

Referencing this link [https://gist.github.com/Artistan/fea3e21f149fdf845e530299bcff37d4]

...you can access the relation data through the paginator, by eager loading the relations after the search call...

```
$prospects = Prospect::search('pizza')->paginate(999999);
$prospects->load('state');
$prospects->load('foodcat');
```

**However I was wondering if there was a way to make the same data available without using the paginator class...**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Looking for the same thing at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure whether I got your question right, but maybe the `with()` function of Eloquent is what you are looking for.

So in your given example you would call something like 
`Prospect::with('state','foodcat')->get()`
in order to retrieve the related models.

[Eager Loading Relationships in Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Eager loading the relations in this fashion works just fine, but in this example you are not fetching from the Algolia search index, you are fetching directly from the database. When you try to use this approach in the same fashion with Algolia, i.e. Prospect::with()->search()->get(), it throws an exception, because the search() functionality is not part of the Eloquent Builder class.